# When is Musaf said?

Tags: tefilla, calendar, musaf

When is the Musaf said?  I know it is part of the Shacharit service.  I mean when as in what holidays, fast days, etc...  Would you say it on Tisha B'av for example.  If not, why?

> At the end of the Torah reading of Pinchas, we read about the additional sacrifices that were offered in the Temple on special days. These additional sacrifices are called musaf (in the singular) or musafin (in the plural), meaning "additions," and they were offered on Shabbat, Rosh Chodesh, Passover, Shavuot, Rosh Hashanah, Yom Kippur, and Sukkot, as well as on the intermediate days (Chol Hamoed) of Passover and Sukkot.

Are the holidays listed the only times you would do musaf?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The red-letter days listed in your question are, indeed, the only times we say it, and for the reason you quote: because those are the days the *musaf* sacrificial offerings were offered to God in the Temple back in the good old days. See Numbers chapters [28](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0428.htm)–[29](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0429.htm).

Comment: Note Musaf is not part of Shacharit. It is it's own service, though it is usually also said in the morning.

Comment: There are other communal additional offerings though which do not merit a Musaf prayer. (Your condition is necessary but insufficient.)

Comment: Thank you, both msh210 and @Double AA ! Your responses helped clarify this for me.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I can't think of any offerings that don't merit a _musaf_ prayer but which meet the description I wrote ("the _musaf_ sacrificial offerings"). What are they?

Comment: @msh210 I see a 3 such sheep [and 1 such goat] mentioned in Leviticus 23. (Your description is somewhat vague. If it means "the sacrificial offering which have a corresponding Tefillat Musaf" then it is trivially true. If you mean "communal offerings of fixed time aside from the Tamid" (or something like that) then my counterexamples hold, I believe.) [Goat is in brackets because there are some _nuschaot_ which do have a prayer for it, but this is not well accepted IME.]

Comment: @DoubleAA [Lev. 23](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/T0323):20 is the _shalme tzibur_ a/k/a _kivse Atzeres_, which I don't recall **ever** hearing called a "_musaf_". But if they are it doesn't matter, as they're brought on the same day as _musafin_ are, so they still pretty much fit my answer ("those are the days the _musaf_ sacrificial offerings were offered"). I don't know what other sheep you refer to.

Comment: @msh210 (The referent was the sheep brought with the 'Omer. I made a silly mistake and forgot to count an additional cow, two rams and seven sheep which have no associated prayer.) There is a Musaf prayer on that day, indeed, but it is not for these animals. See [Rambam Temidin u **Musafin** 8:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=8&hilchos=46&perek=8&hilite=). Re "pretty much fit": see my parenthetical in my previous comment.

Comment: @DoubleAA that _Rambam_ is pretty clear that those _korbanos_ are not _musafin_.

Comment: @msh210 I disagree. He says they aren't Musaf HaYom. They aren't coming qua Yom Tov; they are coming qua the Shtei HaLechem. They are still Musaf. Musaf just means above and beyond the Temidin. I offered two definitions of Musaf above. Are you proposing a third?